# Form not rendering in Modal React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to pop up a form on clicking a button using react bootstrap modal but it's not getting rendered. The form is a separate component defined in another file.

I have imported the form and modal and trying to render as follows

```
import AddTaskForm from './Forms/taskForm';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

```
{
 this.state.open &&
 <Modal 
 show={this.state.open} onHide={this.handleClose}>
 <Modal.body>
 <AddTaskForm />
 </Modal.body> 
 </Modal>
}
```

The states and functions are defined as

```
constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            // visibility: false,
            open: false
        }
    }
handleOpen = () => {
      this.setState({ open: true });
    };

handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({ open: false });
    };
```

The button implemented as

```
<Button variant="contained" color="" className={classes.button} onClick={this.handleOpen}>
<AddIcon className={classes.leftIcon} />
Add a task
</Button>
```

On clicking button blank page pop up. Where am I going wrong?? It's my first hands on experience in react and thus I'm finding it difficult to debug.
Thank you.

Comment: Try to set debugger in your handleOpen to see that you can call to that function or not ?

Comment: First of all,try to debug setting state like this ``this.setState({ open: true }, () => { console.log(this.state.open) })``. Is the console logging?

Comment: ``<Modal.Body>`` not ``<Modal.body>``

Comment: Yess the error was due to incorrect syntax <Modal.body>. Now its working. Thank you!!